# C - Dynamically cast void* in arithmetic

Tags: c

I have a problem at hand and I've sketched a quick program to try describe the issue in easier manner.

Here is a structure I am using. The reason I am using void* is because I want to associate different types with different variables.

```
struct Test_s
{
    void* value;
    size_t size;
};
```

Next, I want to write a function which would accept this structure type as an input:

```
void* func(struct Test_s* t1, struct Test_s* t2)
{
    if (*t1->value != *t2->value)
    {
        return *t1->value;
    }
    else
    {
        return *t2->value;
    }
}
```

The only way I can make this program compile is if I were to typecast void* to some type. The problem I am facing is that I do not know which type it is therefore I cannot brute force it, e.g.:

```
*(int*)t1->value != *(int*)t2->value;
```

(I could deduce it from the size field, this is why I've added it) but I do not know how to dynamically make this typecast. This is possible because it is planned only to use stdint types. How would you solve this problem since it is not possible to pass an argument like (int*), (char*), etc. to a function.

Comment: What about an `union` type for your value and an `enum` tag to describe its type within your struct?

Comment: Would a switch on the size calling different functions work?

Comment: I agree that it is possible with switch, but then I need to implement multiple same functions. They are not this basic as I've demonstrated in this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but simply not possible.  At the CPU’s machine instruction level, the process of adding two integers is different from adding two floats, and both are different from adding 2 longs, etc, etc.  So expecting the compiler to decide at compile time what type of “adding” is meant to happen at runtime is simply not possible in C.

Comment: how exactly are you going to use `func`? There are some tricks that may let you do some generic programming in C.

Comment: I'll make an update of function.

Comment: I've updated it with a general idea.

Comment: The `if` is confusing. What you wrote could be just `return *t1->value;` (`return (a!=b) ? a : b;` is equivalent to `return a;`). Then it comes down to fetching 1,2,4,or 8 bytes (on common architectures anyway) into the return register (the return type should be a larger integer type e.g., `uint64_t`) based on inputted size. That would most optimally be done with a `switch` or an `if`-`else` ladder.

Comment: @Amaterastis "only to use stdint types." --> Might the 2 items compared differ in types?  Might the types differ is sign-ness?

Comment: If you want the type picking to be done at compile time, you need to re-design everything to use `_Generic` and drop the void pointers. It's an entirely different design. Your current design needs an enum and run-time checks. At best you can provide callbacks for certain operations on certain types, but that's cumbersome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `size` tells you the size of the pointed-to-object, you can do:

```
if (memcmp(t1->value, t2->value, t1->size) != 0) { ... }
```

**But notice that not all object types are comparable using `memcmp`.** For instance two structs-objects with equal member values may have different padding-values and will therefore fail on `memcmp`. For floats there are also some special values where `==` and `memcmp` will give different results. **So whether this is a useful solution depends on the types used.**

Further, it may be a good idea to check that `t1->size == t2->size` before calling `memcmp`.

That said, notice that this is wrong

```
return *t1->value;
```

because you defined the function to return a void pointer, i.e. `void* func`, and `*t1->value` is not a void-pointer. It's a dereferenced void-pointer which is illegal to do anyway.

A working function could be:

```
void* func(struct Test_s* t1, struct Test_s* t2)
{
    if (t1->size != t2->size ||
        memcmp(t1->value, t2->value, t1->size) != 0)
    {
        return t1->value;
    }
    else
    {
        return t2->value;
    }
}
```